# Bison - print the prefix notation in a simple calculator

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison

I have created a calculator in Flex and Bison. I need to be able to print the prefix notation of whatever expression I get from the standard input. I was able to easily print the post fix notation, but I am having difficulty doing the prefix notation. Here is what I have accomplished in Bison so far:

```
%{
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int yylex(void);
void yyerror(char *);
int sym[26];
%}

%token INTEGER VARIABLE 

%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%left POWER
%right '!' 



%%
program:
  program statement '\n' 
  |  
  ; 

statement: 
  expr              { printf("\n%d \n", $1); }
  |
  VARIABLE '=' expr { sym[$1] = $3;printf("\n" ); }
  ;

expr:
  INTEGER            {  /*printf("%d",yylval);*/}
  | VARIABLE        { $$ = sym[$1]; printf("%d",sym[$1]);}
  | expr '+' expr   { $$ = $1 + $3; printf("+");}
  | expr '-' expr   { $$ = $1 - $3; printf("-");}
  | expr '*' expr   { $$ = $1 * $3; printf("*");}
  | expr '/' expr   { $$ = $1 / $3; printf("/");}
  | expr POWER expr { $$ = pow($1, $3);printf("pow");}
  | '('  expr  ')'  { $$ = $2;}
  | '!' expr        { $$ = !$2; printf("!");}

  ; 


%%
void yyerror(char *s) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main(void) {
  yyparse();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is your prefix? It looks like postfix.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious problem that you are facing is that the operator is parsed AFTER both the operands are parsed. So you cannot achieve it just with printf. One solution would be create a huge char array (you can make it global) and instead of using printf, you can keep on prepending it. So for instance when you encounter a +, (assuming final is your global variable).

```
char temp[100];
sprintf(temp, "%s%s", "+", final);
strcpy(final, temp);
```

And when you are done parsing, that is when yyparse() returns, you can printf("%s", final);